# Micro-framework for web development in Java

Tags: software-development, java

I want to make a small web site, and preferably in Java, due primarily to my coding partner. I love micro-frameworks such as Flask in Python, but most frameworks in Java are **BIG** and/or slow. Examples of this is the Play Framework and Grails. Hate them both.

I just want a minimal approach, but don't want to code with pure Servlets, and so far I have found two:

The Sinatra inspired [Spark](https://github.com/perwendel/spark), and the similar [Jogger](https://github.com/germanescobar/jogger), which is slightly more recent. I am slightly reluctant to use Jogger, since it is very new and just backed by one guy.

Any other suggestions?

Need to have

- Easy setup/Adapters for common database backends (Postgres, H2, ...)
- Filters/Interceptors for pre/post-processing
- Be easy to work with JSON

Nice to have

- Results converted based on requested content-type (like JAX-RS does)
- Annotations for routing

Comment: @NickWilde added.

Comment: Spark is your best choice I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) allows you to create applications with different options for both backend and frontend.

There is a Yeoman generator, [generator-jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster), to quickly generate the application.

From its documentation page:

> JHipster is a development platform to generate, develop and deploy Spring Boot + Angular / React / Vue Web applications and Spring microservices.

Comment: That was a really solid option. Never heard about it until now. After comparing Spark to JHipster, I guess Spark is what fits my bill the closest: a super-simple understandable piece of software that Does-One-Thing - and is still in active development (but not that much - aka stable). Still, no one suggested it as an answer and JHipster is probably the best alternative for someone who wants something comprehensive, so the vote goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home). I've had great success with it. The only drawback is that it may no longer be in active development. There's very little configuration -- most everything is convention or annotation to override that -- and it works well with Spring and other DI frameworks.

Comment: Stripes was dead in 2014. The homepage is now some japanese spam network.